# Lógica de controllers e services com Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, services

Tenho algumas dúvidas em relação à lógica das funções de busca do controller e do service.

Segue um exemplo de **service**:

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("ProjetosAPI", function ($http, config) {

    var _getProjetos = function (pagina, total) {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/projetos?pagina=" + pagina + "&total=" + total);
    };

    var _getProjetosPorEmpresa = function (pagina, total, empresa) {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/projetos?pagina=" + pagina + "&total=" + total + "&empresa=" + empresa);
    };

    var _getProjetosPorEmpresaData = function (pagina, total, empresa, data) {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/projetos?pagina=" + pagina + "&total=" + total + "&empresa=" + empresa + "&data=" + data);
    };

    return {
        getProjetos: _getProjetos,
        getProjetosPorEmpresa: _getProjetosPoEmpresa,
        getProjetosPorEmpresaData: _getProjetosPoEmpresaData
    };

});
```

Dúvidas:

1- Esta abordagem está "correta"?

2- Se eu precisasse buscar por empresa, data e valor ou somente por data, eu acrescentaria mais uma função? Por exemplo: `getProjetosPorEmpresaDataValor` ou `getProjetoPorData`.

3- No **controller** eu precisaria ter uma função para cada função do **service**, com os devidos parâmetros?

Estou utilizando desta forma até o momento. Na API REST (node.js + express.js) tenho uma única função para `GET /projetos` que trata quais dados trazer de acordo com os parâmetros recebidos na requisição.

Como nunca desenvolvi aplicação grande, tenho várias dúvidas parecidas com essas, se puderem me indicar algum material que ajude nesse sentido seria bom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de escrever seus services. Não há nada de essencialmente errado na sua abordagem.

Existem padrões, no entanto, que são bem populares, como o o [Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) do John Papa. Dito isso, cabe ressaltar que o jeito como você estruturou seu service é o modelo não recomendado pela maior parte da comunidade. As razões para isso estão todas elencadas na seção dos [services](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#services).

Basicamente, o Style Guide diz que é melhor usar declarações de funções para esconder detalhes de implementação, ou seja, manter os membros acessíveis da factory bem no topo do documento para que você consiga enxergar, logo quando abre o arquivo, quais são as funções daquela factory e quais as funções que podem ser acessadas externamente por outros controllers. Isso facilita demais quando o seu service começa a ficar muito longo em aplicações grandes e complexas.

Para otimizar o seu service, ainda, eu aconselharia você modificar os parâmetros da sua função _getProjetos

```
var _getProjetos = function (query) {
    return $http.get(config.baseUrl + query);
};
```

Fazendo isso, você fica com uma função muito mais reusável na sua factory. Para atingir os mesmos resultados, você tem que montar as queries no seu controller de acordo com as exigências de cada call e só passar a string final pro service, que vai executar o GET.

## Exemplos do Style Guide

```
/* avoid */
function dataService() {

  var someValue = '';

  function save() {
    /* */
  };

  function validate() {
   /* */
  };

  return {
    save: save,
    someValue: someValue,
    validate: validate
  };

}

/* recommended */
angular
   .module('app.core')
   .factory('dataservice', dataservice);

function dataService() {

  var someValue = '';

  var service = {
    save: save,
    someValue: someValue,
    validate: validate
  };

  return service;

  ////////////

  function save() {
      /* */
  };

  function validate() {
      /* */
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Essa é mais uma pergunta a respeito de *code review* do que do que utilização de serviços propriamente.

> 1- Esta abordagem está "correta"?

Nada inválido com ela. Pode, porém, ser aprimorada, por exemplo com a adição de *caching* ou *promises* individuais, de acordo com as necessidades do projeto.

> 2- Se eu precisasse buscar por empresa, data e valor ou somente por data, eu acrescentaria mais uma função? Por exemplo: `getProjetosPorEmpresaDataValor` ou `getProjetoPorData`?

Você está utilizando interfaces estáticas para seus métodos. Se a presença de parâmetros é variável, você pode se beneficiar de interfaces abstratas para evitar a criação de um número desnecessário de funções correspondentes às combinações de parâmetros.

Por exemplo, ao invés de:

```
var _getProjetos = function (pagina, total) {
    return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/projetos?pagina=" + pagina + "&total=" + total);
};
```

Você pode implementar a seguinte interface abstrata via objeto:

```
var _getProjetos = function (params) {
    return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/projetos?" + $.param(params);
};
```

`$.param()` converte um objeto para a notação utilizada em *query strings*. Sua chamada ao serviço pode ser feita assim, então:

```
var ret = svc.getProjetos({pagina: 1, total: 10});
// URL gerada: config.baseUrl + "/projetos?pagina=1&total=10";
```

Se desejar adicionar um código de empresa:

```
var ret = svc.getProjetos({pagina: 1, total: 10, empresa: 128 });
// URL gerada: config.baseUrl + "/projetos?pagina=1&total=10&empresa=128";
```

> 3- No controller eu precisaria ter uma função para cada função do service, com os devidos parâmetros?

Não. Isso dependerá exclusivamente do seu modelo de implementação.